# How to find a word in a value of object and apply condition in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have array of objects which I'm using map on. But the thing is, in that map I want to search the specific word from object value.

Like I have a array of objects like this:

```
[
      {
         "groupName": "TwoFactTest",
         "groupId": ""
      },
      {
         "groupName": "OU_AHMEDABAD"
         "groupId": ""
      }
]
```

I have done react code like this:

```
{
  importedgroups.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
        <GroupIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} />
        {/* <OUIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} 
            /> */}
        <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>

        <TableCell
          align="left"
          style={{ font: "normal normal 600 14px Open Sans" }}
        >
          {row.groupImportedAs}
        </TableCell>

        <TableCell>
          <Button
            href="javascript:void(0)"
            color="primary"
            disableRipple
            onClick={() => removeGroup(row, index)}
            style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "flex-end",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
              }}
            >
              <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon
                style={{
                  marginBottom: "-7px",
                  width: "14px",
                  height: "14px",
                  marginRight: "2px",
                }}
              />{" "}
              Remove
            </div>
          </Button>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  });
}
```

I want to perform operation that when a word of `OU` is contained in object value, then put `<OUIcon>` else `<GroupIcon>`. I have commented out `OUIcon`.

Any fix?. How to do it in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render component with conditional rendering.

Try something like below:-

```
{importedgroups.map((row, index) => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={row.name}>
            {row.groupName.includes('OU') ? (
              <OUIcon
                style={{
                  marginRight: '5px',
                  display: 'inline-flex',
                  verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <GroupIcon
                style={{
                  marginRight: '5px',
                  display: 'inline-flex',
                  verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }}
              />
            )}

            <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>

            <TableCell
              align="left"
              style={{ font: 'normal normal 600 14px Open Sans' }}
            >
              {row.groupImportedAs}
            </TableCell>

            <TableCell>
              <Button
                href="javascript:void(0)"
                color="primary"
                disableRipple
                onClick={() => removeGroup(row, index)}
                style={{ textTransform: 'none' }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'flex-end',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
                  }}
                >
                  <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon
                    style={{
                      marginBottom: '-7px',
                      width: '14px',
                      height: '14px',
                      marginRight: '2px'
                    }}
                  />{' '}
                  Remove
                </div>
              </Button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
```

Note:- This will render `OUIcon` if `groupName` contains `OU` at any place in string. If you are certain that your data will contain `OU_` for all valid names than you need to update condition.

Comment: It throws me this error: `TypeError: row.groupName.contains is not a function`. Please fix this?

Comment: @progpro My Bad, I have updated condition. Basically string have include method to check included string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
        {
           row.groupName.startsWith('OU') ? 
           <OUIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} /> : 
<GroupIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} />
         }
        <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>

        <TableCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional rendering, doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Example:

```
{
  importedgroups.map((row, index) => {
    let icon;
    if (/OU_/.test(row.groupName)) {
      icon = (<OUIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} />);
    } else {
      icon = (<GroupIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px', display: 'inline-flex', verticalAlign: 'bottom' }} />);
    }

    return (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
        {icon}
        <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>
    ...
```